# if query has no rows in laravel 5 through AJAX call, "readyState": 4 is appearing in console

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel-5

I have a query in my laravel 5 application that fetches some data from table. When there is data in table then it is showing data on screen, but if table has now row against query, then `"readyState": 4` error is showing in console. my code looks like below.

```
public function some_function($accId){
    $q = DB::Select("SELECT ca.*, ch.* FROM credit_accounts as ca, credit_history as ch WHERE ch.acc_id=ca.id AND ch.acc_id='$accId' ORDER BY ch.acc_id DESC");

    if (count($q) > 0){
      // if query fetch some data, then this if condition works fine
      $val="condition true";
    }
    else{
      // if there is no data against this query then else block not runs and return "readyState": 4 error. but it should return "condition false".
      $val = "condition false";
    }

      return $val;
}
```

Please guide me that why this error is appearing.

Comment: So where do you call this method and what do you do with the result of this method

Comment: this is just a dummy method which shows functionality like my real method. Anyhow i'm fetching data from database, then I check if there are any rows then return that data. if there is no row then i'm returning an error message in else block. if there is no row fetched then error message should be returned, but "readyState": 4 is returned instead.

Comment: `"readyState": 4 is returned` in the javascript, means that a result has been returned, as you return something, regardless of whether there are rows or not, that is good. Now in the javascript you have to read what you returned and decide what to do based on what was returned

Comment: ofcourse i can do that, but logically on the server side, if query found no row, then it should run the else block and return me error message, i'm wondering why there is error when query finds no data, and works fine when there is data.

Comment: Yes, but the error message is NOT an AJAX ERROR. It is a good return of data, you just have to see that in the normal success phase of the javascript

Comment: yes bro, it is not AJAX error, this is server side error and occurs only when query fails to fetch any data. i'm simply asking why it is not running the else block? i'm new to laravel, is there any other way to run query? or any other way to check number of rows count?
And thanks for your time :)